# writing to stdout = output_file gives different file length than invoking the program direct via shell

Tags: python

I'm trying to get some output from an external program, invoked by a python script to be redirected from stdout to a file.

```
output_file = open(list_file,"wb")
programm_aufruf = './deadsp -b '+ ausgabedatei
#print programm_aufruf
args = shlex.split(programm_aufruf)
#print args
sub_p = subprocess.Popen(args,stdout=output_file)
print 'warten auf disassambler '
time.sleep(0.002)
poll = sub_p.poll()
while poll == None:
    print '.\r',
    poll = sub_p.poll()
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.05)
sys.stdout.flush()
output_file.flush
output_file.close
```

But if the script invokes the external program the generated file size is 118kb, invoking the program via shell it gives 162kb of file size, so some of the dis-assembled code is missing.

I've tried to `flush()` stdout, flush the file...nothing helps.
Currently I'm developing under MacOS but should not matter anyway, I don't have a Linux VM to hand at the moment.

Comment: Is it `output_file.close` or `output_file.close()` in your actual code? Because without the parenthesis it won't call the method

Comment: Same with the "call" to `output_file.flush`.  And what's the point of printing `.\r` 20 times a second?  If you want to see progress, then skip the `\r`.

Comment: Hi, that's it. Yes it did not execute file.close() because of missing "()". But this was due to a file open before this section. Thanks a lot!  "\r" should give an output like .... but did not work at all printing "." gives output like ".  .  ."